# How to declare a function in a trigger - Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, function, triggers

I dont know how to do this trigger with an internal function in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER promo 
AFTER INSERT ON promociones 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE nomb VARCHAR2(20); times NUMBER; cont NUMBER;
FUNCTION veces (promo VARCHAR2(20)) 
RETURN NUMBER as cont 
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*) INTO cont FROM promociones WHERE id2=promo;
RETURN cont;
END veces; 
BEGIN 
    times:= veces(:new.id2); 
    SELECT nombre into nomb FROM promociones WHERE id=:new.id2;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nomb || times);
END;
/
```

Then says me: 'Encountered the simbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % default character. The symbol ":=" was substitutd for "(" to continue.
'
'Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: constant exception (an identifier) (a double-quoted delimited-identifier) table long double ref char timestamp interval date binary national character nchar.'
'Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting on of the following: begin function pragme procedure'

How is the real syntax of this trigger? help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the "(" of the parameter VARCHAR2(20).
When coding functions in PLSQL, do not include precisions.

```
FUNCTION veces (promo VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
as 
    cont NUMBER(38);
BEGIN 
    SELECT count(*) INTO cont FROM promociones WHERE id2=promo;
    RETURN cont;
END veces;
```

Comment: I put something like: `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER promo 
AFTER INSERT ON promociones 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE nomb VARCHAR2(20); times NUMBER; cont NUMBER;
FUNCTION veces (promo VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER as cont
BEGIN veces
SELECT count(*) INTO cont FROM promociones WHERE id2=promo; 
RETURN cont;
END veces; 
BEGIN 
 times:=veces(:new.id2); 
 SELECT nombre into nomb FROM promociones WHERE id = :new.id2;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nomb || times);
END;
/` and say Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting a constant excepcion (a identifier) (...)

Comment: @IvanG4Life data type of cont is missing. It must cont NUMBER(38);